# Switching between two different textures or UV maps in Meshlab

Tags: meshlab

I will be generating a mesh outside of Meshlab, but viewing it in Meshlab. I haven't decided on a format yet. I want to have a single file that would contain all the data - the triangles, uv maps and the textures.

However, I have 2 textures between which I want to switch. They should **not be visible at the same time**. Imagine I want to show the mesh with some flame texture in one moment, but with a flower texture in another - the user should be able to switch between them. I tried searching for something similar, but all I find are questions on how to combine multiple textures into a single visible one, which is not what I want. There is a way to switch the texture file via `Filters->Texture->Set Texture`, but I'd like something less cumbersome.

Is there some way in Meshlab to easily switch between textures/UV maps? If yes, for what formats is this supported?

Comment: Why is `Set Texture` cumbersome? What did you expect in exchange of current `Set Texture`?

Comment: The mesh is going to be viewed by people who are not very technical and I need this to be a simple button or shortcut, not 3 levels deep in a menu and then requiring you to fill out some fields. There isn't even a file dialogue and you have to set the size manually...it's not very user friendly. I could even have them use a different program than Meshlab, but I haven't found anything comparable yet.

Comment: Do you plain to use meshlab just as a viewer? What other Meshlab capabilities are you planing to use? Maybe a supersimple viewer using [libIGL](https://libigl.github.io/) is enough for you

Comment: Yeah, writing my own viewer is another option, but I was hoping to use some standard tool if possible, and everybody around here already knows Meshlab a little. I don't really have much time to write a custom one, make it work on both Linux and Windows, and also distribute it among users...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sad to say... but current meshlab does support loading files with several textures (for example .ply and .obj), but AFAIK it does not let the user choose the texture/material to apply in each moment.
It should be very easy to write a custom plugin to rotate between textures, but it is not done.

One easy alternative you can use and teach for your users is this:

- In your external program, create two separate files, each one with one texture. (called texture1.ply and texture2.ply in this example)
- Open both files with meshlab using command line "meshlab texture1.ply texture2.ply". You can see an strange combination of both meshes by now, because both meshes are being rendered.

[image: Both meshes active]

- Tell your users that they can change current view with **Ctrl-Click in the eye icon** near of the name of each mesh. This will activate one mesh and deactivate every else.

[image: Ctrl-Click in texture2]

- You can rotate/move the camera in any view and repeat **Ctrl-Click in the eye icon** to change to another mesh, keeping the current camera position.

[image]

Of course, if you modify a mesh (for example, selecting and deleting some faces) the changes affects only to one mesh, not the other.

Comment: Thanks. Sad to hear that Meshlab doesn't support it. I'd rather not have several files, because that creates a lot of data duplication that I can't afford :(

Comment: Then, your next option is using an external viewer or hire somebody to write a meshlab plugin to change the texture with a button. It is not hard to do, but it is not done :-(

Comment: Yeah I'm currently thinking about writing a web viewer because distributing the software would be painful otherwise (same with a Meshlab plugin). But it really helps to know that Meshlab doesn't have it, because then I don't have to pointlessly look for it anymore, so you saved me a lot of effort :)